# How do i deal with negation when converting from Infix to Postfix form and evaluating

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

how do i deal with negation? i mean for example:

- -(3 + 2) * -(9 / -3)
- -((((-4 + 5))))

when I convert it to Postfix form the result is:

- 3 2 + * - 9 / 3 - -
- 4 - 5 + -

but here when I evaluate each one it will give errors because of the minus, how do I solve this?

Comment: ... Implement it. I guess you don't know the algorithm to do it, in that case use [tag:algorithm].

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246787/handling-unary-minus-for-shunting-yard-algorithm) and [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254080/infix-to-postfix-algorithm-that-takes-care-of-unary-operators).

Comment: You need to distinguish `-` as negation and `-` as substraction. These are two different operators.